# Did Jacob and Esau have other brothers?

Tags: avot-patriarch-fathers, parashat-toldot, esav

In Bereishit 27:29, Isaac's Blessing of Jacob contains:

"You shall be a master over your brothers, and your mother's sons shall bow down to you."

Are there any explanations in the literature explaining why the plural was used, or perhaps stories of other brothers not in Tanach? 1st D. Hayamim 1:34 only lists Esau and Israel. Bereishit 25:21-22 makes it look unlikely that Rebekah had more, but perhaps she did?

Comment: dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13493/472

Comment: ..sorry.. Monica, it looks like you already had it covered..I did some searches thinking it had to be on here somewhere already, but missed it..

Comment: Gary, no need to apologize!  Dupes aren't bad; if you couldn't find the other question, then your way of asking about it was different enough to not hit it and now yours will help people find those answers.  (Note: I asked the other question, which is why I remembered it.)  I'll go ahead and mark this as a dupe, then.

Comment: ...the answers over there nicely show that it WAS a concern in the literature...but none of the explanations really ring true..oh, well..just shows how handy a time machine would be for linguistics enthusiasts...

Comment: Gary, sometimes answers come late (this dupe led to a new one on the other question), so an answer that satisfies you more may yet come along.  Of course, feel free to publicize any questions you'd like more input on using social media or other means; we'll always welcome more users contributing to the site!